# How to divert connection or packet before routing decision entering the default chain using iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

before the packets ports (443) entering the firewall i would like to divert incoming packet of server (443) to input chain goes to FORWARD chain
so thats the incoming packets 100.43.xx.xx --sport 443 are send it to FORWARD instead of input chain
and this is my nf_conntrack

```
tcp 6 431977 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.xx.xx dst=100.43.xx.xx sport=33575 dport=443
src=100.43.xx.xx dst=192.168.xx.xx sport=443 dport=33575 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
```

how to configure this in OUTPUT,FORWARD,POST AND PREROUTING CHAIN

my iptables rules

```
root@kali:~#iptables-save
-A POSTROUTING -o dms0 -j MASQUERADE
-A INPUT -i dms0 -p tcp -s 100.43.xx.xx --sport 443 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i dms0 -p udp -m multiport --sport 22,443,1080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
root@kali:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORIGINAL_DESTINATION='100.43.1.1'
NEW_DESTINATION='100.43.1.2'
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d "$ORIGINAL_DESTINATION" -p tcp --dport 443 \
-j DNAT --to-destination "$NEW_DESTINATION"
```

Comment: Explanation needed.